# pyodbc InterfaceError

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm having trouble connecting to a MS SQL Server database via Python using pyODBC:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                       'SERVER=tmw-prod-lo\\SQL65;'
                       'DATABASE=TMWSuite;'
                       'UID=VENTURE\\acoop;'
                       'PWD=RaNdoM!'))
```

This results in:

```
InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'VENTURE\\acoop'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'VENTURE\\acoop'. (18456)")
```

I'm pretty confident I've got all the parameters right and that I need to escape the backslashes in the server and username as above, correct?  So it just looks like a permissions issue but I wanted to rule out any other issues first.

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious from error message: `Login failed for user`. It seems like permission/ login/ password issue.

Comment: Several questions: a) OS: Windows,Linux,other?  b) Authenthification Mode: Windows  or SQLServer?

Comment: @thor - it's not so obvious. I suspect that `pyodbc` is trying to connect thru SQLServer Authentification and @ACoop provides Windows credentials

Comment: @ACoop: can you connect using `sqlcmd`/`bcp`/`other cli` to SQLServer?

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes this is on Windows, I was providing Windows credentials via which I'm able to connect using SQL Server Management Studio.  IT set up a new account that works, there may have also been an issue with the backslash in my username (as the new one does not have one), but not sure.